# getting all of the currecny values out of a text file

Tags: python

im having trouble with getting my python code to read through a text file and add together all of the monetary values. the code seemed to be working fine on my pc, but as soon as i transferred the file to my mac it gave me a whole slew of errors. here is the code

```
#!usr/bin/python
import sys

def findnum(x):
    list = x.split(' ')
    index = 0
    listindex = -1
    numlist = []
    sum = 0

    for w in list:
        if ((w.strip('. n,')).isalpha() != True and w[0].isalpha() != True and w[-2].isdigit() == True):
            numlist.append(w)
            listindex += 1

    while listindex >= 0:
        sum += float(numlist[listindex].strip('$ n.'))
        listindex -= 1
    return sum
def main():
    text = open(sys.argv[1])
    x = text.readline()
    sum = 0
    if len(x) > 0:
        findnum(x)
        while len(x) > 0:
            sum += findnum(x)
            x = text.readline()
    print '{0:.2f}'.format(sum)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

here is the text
This is your invoice from the ACME materials
company.  You received 50lbs of sand at a
cost of $40.  The brick we delivered is 70.5
for the 75Kg.  In addition, we delivered 30yards
of sod for $200.00.  Delivery charge is $35.

so i need to add 40 + 70.5 + 200 +35
i keep getting a index out of range error..
anyone think they can help me out?

Comment: Does your pc and Mac run the same version? Also, can we see a traceback? Also, did you read documentation for sys.argv?

Comment: What is your error, Does it give you a line it's failing on.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "matt.py", line 33, in <module>
    main() 
  File "matt.py", line 28, in main
    sum += findnum(x)
  File "matt.py", line 13, in findnum
    if ((w.strip('. n,')).isalpha() != True and w[0].isalpha() != True and w[-2].isdigit() == True):
IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: Those w[] indexes are raising index errors, as the traceback is telling you. Did you print w prior to evaluation to see what is in it?

Comment: i want to add the values to w

Answer (score 3):

```
import re
print re.findall('(\$\d+(?:\.\d{2})?)', x)
```